# How can i use Tailwind using Sass on Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, tailwind-css

I wanna using tailwind with sass on vue js, I'm following tailwind docs but still got this error

this is my **depedency**, postcss is up to date

```
"dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
```

this is my **postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
  ]
}
```

any solution? how can i use tailwind with sass preprocessor on vue js? Thanks all.

> Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8

[image: error from postcss]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to uninstall that dependencies which are related to postcss and tailwind :

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

then install them using the following command :

```
npm i -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

according to [this section](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build)

> As of v2.0, Tailwind CSS depends on PostCSS 8. Because PostCSS 8 is only a few months old, many other tools in the ecosystem haven't updated yet

Comment: Hello @Boussadjra Brahim, how are you?
i still got this error, can it not be installed using yarn? or tailwind specifically for npm only? Thank you

Comment: fine, thank you, try to replace `npm uninstall` by `yarn remove` and `npm i` by `yarn add`